# How to verify if the nth element exist with DIDOM html parser

Tags: php, css-selectors, html-parsing

I am using DiDom html parser library. From it's documentation (https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM#verify-if-element-exists):

If you need to check if element exist and then get it:

```
if ($document->has('.post')) {
    $elements = $document->find('.post');
    // code
}
```

But what if i need to check existance of n-th element of array of elements with '.post' class, for example:

```
$elements = $document->find('.post')[1];
```

The code below doesn't work and throws errors:

```
if ($document->has('.post')[1]) {
    $elements = $document->find('.post')[1];
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. DiDOM **has()** method doesn't offers nth-child option. So i've used pseudo-classes selector nth-child(n) to check appearance of n-th element. 
The code looks now:

```
    if ($document->find('.post:nth-child(2)')) {
        $elements = $document->find('.post:nth-child(2)'))[0]->text();
    } else { 
    echo "there are no such item"; 
    }
```